# Does visual studio code have an extension that backs up projects at intervals and allows "time travel"

Tags: visual-studio-code, backup

What I want is an extension for Visual Studio Code that will periodically make a copy of my project files and store them somewhere.  The extension should allow the user to jump back in time and find all their work as of a certain time.  For instance, something that could back up my files every half hour and allow me to jump back in time so that (at 4:30) I could revert to 4:00 or 3:30 or 3:00 .... etc.

Comment: Great question - I wonder why there's been no answer if 5 months...(Actually I'm coming from an editor that I could configure to create a new backup-file with every save. Lots of space wasted - maybe. Lifesaver - for sure! I'd like to do the same in Code, but haven't found an extension to do so. "LocalHistory" did not do what is was supposed to.)